# Minimize edges of a directed unweighted graph

Tags: graphs, optimization

I need to find an algorithm to find a sub-graph $G'=(V, E')$ of a directed unweighted graph $G = (V, E)$ where for all $(u, v)\in E$ there exists a path in $G'$ from $u$ to $v$ and the size of $E'$ is minimal.

As an example, $(1, 2) (2, 3) (1, 3)$ reduces to $(1, 2) (2, 3)$. Additionally, $(1, 2) (2, 3) (1, 3) (3, 1)$ reduces to $(1, 2) (2, 3) (3, 1)$.

This is not an MST (or arborescence) problem since we care every vertex as a root hence Edmond's algorithm does not work.

I am clueless at this point. At least a hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that the *transitive closure* $H$ of a digraph $G$ has the properties that

> - (1) there is a directed path from $u$ to $v$ in $H$ iff there is a directed path from $u$ to $v$ in $G$, and
> - (2) there is no graph with fewer arcs than $H$ that satisfies condition (1).

The difference to your problem is that you require $H$ to be a *subgraph of $G$*, so it's not exactly a transitive closure you want. But note that for this problem there *are* polynomial-time algorithms.

Instead, Moyles and Thompson [1] consider what I believe is your problem, i.e., the problem of finding the smallest subgraph $G'$ of $G$ such that there is to a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G'$ whenever there is a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G$. They give an algorithm (see Section 4) for the problem which runs in exponential-time, so it's likely not practical for even moderately-sized digraphs.

In fact, your problem is NP-hard and it has been studied in the literature. For instance, Khuller, Raghavachari and Young [2] give a polynomial-time approximation algorithm with a guarantee of 1.64. On a quick skim, their algorithm seem reasonable to implement and thus practical; another approach is of course to rely on other tools such as metaheuristics.

---

[1] [Moyles, Dennis M., and Gerald L. Thompson. "An algorithm for finding a minimum equivalent graph of a digraph." Journal of the ACM (JACM) 16.3 (1969): 455-460.](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/321526.321534)

[2] [Khuller, Samir, Balaji Raghavachari, and Neal Young. "Approximating the minimum equivalent digraph." SIAM Journal on Computing 24.4 (1995): 859-872.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0205040.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

There is no polynomial-time algorithm for your problem, unless $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$.

Let $H$ be a connected undirected graph with at least $2$ vertices and consider the directed graph $G$ obtained by replacing each undirected edge {u,v} of $H$ with the pair of directed edges $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$.

If there is a Hamiltonian path traversing the vertices $\langle u_0, \dots, u_{n-1}, u_n = u_0 \rangle$ of $H$, in order, then the set of $n$ edges $\{ (u_i, u_{(i+1) \bmod n}) \mid i=0,\dots,n-1\}$ of $G$ induces a subgraph $G'$ with your property.

If there is a subgraph $G'$ of $G$ with at most $n$ edges that satisfies your property, then it must have exactly $n$ edges. Moreover the in-degree and the out-degree of each vertex must be exactly $1$, and the undirected version $H'$ of $G'$ must be connected. In other words $G'$ is a cycle that that traverses each vertex of $G$ exactly once, showing that $H'$ is a Hamiltonian path of $H$.